# Angular4 + AoT and two projects with common code results in duplicate declarations error

Tags: angular, webpack-2, angular2-aot

I have an Angular4 project that I've developed which is split into two main projects: the main application that most of our end-users hit and a management application that privileged users hit. These apps both share some common code. Here's the general folder structure:

```
-src
  -app
    -common (contains several subfolders for utilities, pipes, models, etc.)
    -main (contains the main angular4 app with associated module, route, and lazy loaded component files)
    -management (contains the management angular4 app with associated module, route, and lazy loaded component files)
```

I'm using webpack2 to package up the projects and everything has been working great with JiT compilation but now I'm trying to enable AoT but I'm getting errors due to duplicate declarations:

```
Error: Type OrderByPipe in W:/MyApp/src/app/common/pipes/orderBy.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: 
SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/main/shared.module.ts and SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/management/shared.module.ts!
Please consider moving OrderByPipe in W:/MyApp/src/app/common/pipes/orderBy.ts to a higher module that imports SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/main/shared.module.ts and SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/management/shared.module.ts.
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes OrderByPipe in W:/MyApp/src/app/common/pipes/orderBy.ts then import that NgModule in SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/main/shared.module.ts and SharedModule in W:/MyApp/src/app/management/shared.module.ts
```

In this case OrderByPipe is defined in my common folder. These two projects only point to the shared common code and there are no connections between them. I have exclusions in my webpack config to prevent (I assumed) one project from looking at files in another project but it looks like that's not working the way I would expect? Here's my webpack config for the main project:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ngToolsWebpack = require('@ngtools/webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        MyAppApp: './src/app/main/main.ts',
        polyfills: './src/app/main/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './src/app/main/vendor.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/host')],
                use: [{ loader: '@ngtools/webpack' }, { loader: 'angular-router-loader' }]
            },
            {   test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/host')],
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/host')],
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]' }]
            },
            {
                test: /myapp-main-core\.scss$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app/css'),
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: [{ loader: "css-loader?sourceMap" }, { loader: "sass-loader?sourceMap" }] })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/host'), helpers.root('src', 'app/css')],
                use: ['to-string-loader'].concat(ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ 
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMapp'] }))
            }
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('app'),
        publicPath: 'https://localhost:8080/app/',
        filename: 'js/[name].js?[hash]-' + process.env.buildNumber,
        chunkFilename: 'js/MyAppApp-[id].chunk.js?[hash]-' + process.env.buildNumber
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['MyAppApp', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/app/main/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/myapp-main-core.css'),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('doesnotexist')
        ),
        new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
            entryModule: './src/app/main/app.module#AppModule'
        })
    ]
};
```

I'm at a loss as to why the process is considering the management app when I'm clearly excluding it's folder from the webpack config. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but haven't a clue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 7/17/2017:**
I created a new tsconfig.json file (tsconfig.main.aot.json) and added an exclusion for the management directory within that and then pointed the webpack config to that file in the AoTPlugin configuration and that seems to have gotten past the duplicate declaration error I was seeing but now I'm having issues with the extract-text-webpack-plugin so I guess I've got something wrong with how it's configured for AoT:

```
Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I add a one this that could be a `pipe` to a `component` in two different modules, so this might be because its is two different ptoject. The trick I always do is to create a new `*.module.ts` file and imports the component or which ever one thing gives trouble; then import the new module to anywhere you want.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [
    YouComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    YouComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class commonsModule {}
```

Comment: The exclusion in the tsconfig file solved the initial problem and I ended up just removing the extract text webpack plugin as I couldn't figure out that issue. Now I have a different issue but I'll open a new thread for that. Thanks for the help.